# play sound while sliding finger on iphone

Tags: iphone, audio

i like to add the function playing sounds when either sliding fingers on the surface to my iphone app. the sounds are playing now only when pushing buttons.
i suppose this works with TouchesMoved, but i don't know how to implement the "AVAudioPlayer" code to the touches event code.
please any code sample, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I'm aware, TouchesMoved is used to trigger events on the screen (when 'moved over') which in turn can trigger sound events. I don't beleive there is a way you can produce a sound when the user is just 'sliding' around the screen and not interacting with any objects.

This is something I've looked into myself but didn't come up with a solution, but I'll hopefully be corrected in this thread if wrong!

Comment: you are right, what i mean is to play sounds move over objects like with the minipiano:
http://phobos.apple.com/WebObjects/MZStore.woa/wa/viewSoftware?id=289333900
or: kalimba free:
http://discovolos.com/redirects/redirect.php?App=KalimbaFreeSite&Key=KalimbaFreeWebLink
i'm hardly looking for any tutorial

Answer (score 0):

You can instantiate an `AVAudioPlayer` inside of the `touchesMoved:withEvent:` method and play a sound. You need to keep a strong reference to each `AVAudioPlayer` you create or else you will not hear a thing.

To keep track of multiple `AVAudioPlayer`s store them in an array, and remove them from the array when they are finished playing (which you can find out using the `audioPlayerDidFinishPlaying:successfully:` delegate method).

Keep in mind that `touchesMoved:withEvent:` may be triggered in a super high tempo, so your array may grow too large. It's wise to only play a sound when something acutally happens on the screen, such as the next piano key being touched, or to keep a counter and only play a sound every n touches.